# Worklight, Java SQL Adapter, Adapter deployment failed

Tags: java, sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Im following [Java SQL Adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/comment-page-1/) tutorial from IBM worklight.
When I deployed both RSSAdapter and UserAdapter from sample code, the error console is

> Adapter deployment failed: The adapter was built with a later version of Java than is used to run the server.

Im using JDK version 7. Howerver, I also try to downgrade JDK to verion 6, but it still doesn't work.

[Image for error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxnidec5gbwuttm/LaterVerJava.jpg?dl=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change compilance level.

The Java 8 compiler will produce class files in the Java 8 version of the class file format, and accept Java 8 source files. JRE 6 can't load this version, because it was created after JRE 6 was.

If you set the compliance level to "JRE 6", it will instead compile Java 6 source files into Java 6 class files.

Right click on the project, choose properties.

[image]